# Document save by email?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, email, document, update

I have an intranet that has 5-6 department-wise sub-sites, each sub-site has 3-5 document libraries.
My requirements are **User sends email to a particular Email-Id and the email attachment will automatically save in the particular Document Library.**

*I know we can use OneDrive synced with the particular Document Library, but for that the user would need to save the document in his/her device first. But we want to avoid that as there are so many documents coming to us via email and saving them all to our devices and then removing it afterwards would be challenge for us.*

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Incoming Email for the document library where you want to save the documents, once you configured the incoming email you can send mail to list so that it will save attachments to list. Follow steps here to  [configure Incoming email for your farm](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc262947.aspx) and to [configure settings for library](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Enable-and-configure-e-mail-support-for-a-list-or-library-dcaf44a0-1d9b-451a-84c7-6c52e7db908e#bmdoclib)